# orientation tablet vs phone

Tags: android, android-orientation

So i just tested an app that i have been testing on phone devices, on a samsung tablet.

The application updates graphics based on accelermoter data and i noticed that on the tablet it is treating landscape as portrait.. its fine on a naturally portrait mode device..

any ideas how i can ajust this so it works on both:

```
public class ARLaunch extends Activity {

/** Open Camera View **/    
private CamLayer camPreview;
/** Open Camera View **/ 
private GLLayer glView;

private WakeLock mWakeLock;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // requesting to turn the title OFF
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // making it full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //Set Screen Orientation
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    try{
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");


        //Create Intance of Camera
        camPreview = new CamLayer(this.getApplicationContext());

        //Create Instance of OpenGL
        glView = new GLLayer(this);

        //FrameLayOut for holding everything
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        // set as main view
        setContentView(frame);

        // add Camera to view 
        frame.addView(camPreview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        frame.addView(glView);



    } catch(Exception e){}
}
/** Remember to resume the glSurface  */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
    this.mWakeLock.acquire();
    } catch (Exception ex){}
    glView.onResume();
    glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
}
/** Also pause the glSurface  */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{
        this.mWakeLock.release();
    } catch (Exception ex){}

    glView.onPause();

}

public void displayOri(float acc, float ori){

}
```

}

```
public class PhoneOrientation {
private SensorManager sensorMan;
private Sensor sensorAcce;
private Sensor sensorMagn;
private SensorEventListener listener;
private float matrix[]=new float[16];
private Context ctx;

public PhoneOrientation(Context context) {
    ctx = context;
}

public void start(Context context) {
    listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        private float orientation[]=new float[3];
        private float acceleration[]=new float[3];

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1){}

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt) {
            int type=evt.sensor.getType();

            //Smoothing the sensor data a bit seems like a good idea.
            if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
                orientation[0]=(orientation[0]*1+evt.values[0])*0.5f;
                orientation[1]=(orientation[1]*1+evt.values[1])*0.5f;
                orientation[2]=(orientation[2]*1+evt.values[2])*0.5f;
            } else if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                acceleration[0]=(acceleration[0]*2+evt.values[0])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[1]=(acceleration[1]*2+evt.values[1])*0.33334f;
                acceleration[2]=(acceleration[2]*2+evt.values[2])*0.33334f;
            }
            if ((type==Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) || (type==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) {
                float newMat[]=new float[16];
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "accel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
                SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(newMat, null, acceleration, orientation);
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(newMat,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
                        newMat);
                matrix=newMat;
            }
        }
    };

    sensorMan = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorAcce = sensorMan.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
    sensorMagn = sensorMan.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD).get(0);

    sensorMan.registerListener(listener, sensorAcce, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    sensorMan.registerListener(listener, sensorMagn, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);      
}

public float[] getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}

public void finish() {
    sensorMan.unregisterListener(listener);
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this post: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Also, don't use a wake lock just to keep the screen on while your activity is visible. Use the KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag on a view instead and you can drop the wake lock permission.

Comment: hmm, i don't know if that article really helps me..  i have edited my code above to show you my phone orientation class..

Comment: and the wake lock was never really working.. but your solution does.. thanks